# Inconsistent neural network results when using sklean and seed

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, neural-network, random-seed

After running a neural network in sklearn, i am receiving inconsistant results, even after implementing the seed function. each time i run the code, i receive different values for MSE and R squared for each tested seed value. These values can range greatly with R squared being anything between -0.1 to 0.6. Im wondering if its a data issue as i only have 22 columns and 241 rows. Ive also tried setting

```
mlp=MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(22,22,22),max_iter=2000,learning_rate_init=0.001,random_state=0)
```

as well as changing the value of the random_state. 
below is my code. Many thanks

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import numpy as np
data=pd.read_csv(r'''D:\PhD\1styear\machinelearning\NNforF2050\DATAnnF2050.csv''')
print(data.shape)
print(data.dtypes)

x=data.drop('EnergyConsumpManuf',axis=1)


y=data['EnergyConsumpManuf']


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler=StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(x_train)
x_train=scaler.transform(x_train)
x_test=scaler.transform(x_test)

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor 
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from math import sqrt

for i in range(15):
    print('np.random.seed(%d)'%(i))
    np.random.seed(i)
    mlp=MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(22,22,22),max_iter=2000,learning_rate_init=0.001)
    mlp.fit(x_train,y_train)
    predictions=mlp.predict(x_test)
    print('MSE train: ',metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test,predictions))
    RMS=sqrt(metrics.mean_squared_error(y_test,predictions))
    print('RMS',RMS)
    RTWO=sklearn.metrics.r2_score(y_test,predictions)
    print('RTWO',RTWO)
    print('MAE',metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test,predictions))
```

Comment: Set the `np.random.seed(i)` at the top of the script. Or else, use `random_state` in everywhere you find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `random_state` parameter of `train_test_split` function as well. Without fixed random state, data is split randomly each time, that is why results change each time you run the code.